# should we be accepting answers sooner than later?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I'm seeing questions with >=2 answers on the SE. The answers seem to be detailed and target the question (a subjective call of course).

Considering we still need many 'well-reputed' members on the Beta, shouldn't we be doing a run on accepting answers (the accepted answer gets +15 points, and upvotes typically follow).

Comment: I'm wondering about this too. I've also asked questions to which there are often multiple good answers, and I'm not sure if I should just accept one over another one when multiple answers are good.

Comment: It's expected that it will take at least a year to reach the reputation goals for Beta -- the "90 day" timeframe was abandoned long ago.  Trying to push it faster will just cause problems.

Answer (score 4):

Good to remember about accepting the answers!

I tend to wait for some times because seeing an accepted answer may discourage people to give other answers (??).

> Considering we still need many 'well-reputed' members on the Beta

It doesnt seem we will get much difficulty to get  the 5 users with +3000pts and the 10 users with +2000ps, but it may be more difficult to get the 150users with +200pts, so seeing a good answer from a user that has less 200pts encourages me to accept it sooner. Also, it will encourage people who are less active on the site to get more involved.

Comment: I agree re: waiting a little. You can also change which answer you accept if you find a different one is a more appropriate fit.

Answer (score 3):

The general custom on StackExchange is to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer in order to give people in different time zones a chance.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it seems to me that a quick -ish decision on an accepted answer is good. We need more people with lots of points, and an accept is +15 points, and also generates a lot of attention (and its resulting upvotes).

The questioner can always change the best answer if  a better one comes up after all (I've done this a couple of times).