# Many questions without accepted answer - what to do?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I just noted something I find a bit curious: someone posts a question, gets a few answers, and some nice and informative answers get upvoted and show up at the top. However, it seems most OPs do not ever mark one of the answers as "accepted".

As an example: from a quick count of my "Top Questions" page today, only 4 out of 20 questions have an accepted answer. Granted, some are fairly recent questions that might get an accepted answer later on, but this behaviour doesn't seem to change when I look at older questions.

I find this a bit of a shame, as many users put quite a bit of time and effort writing well-explained and detailed answers, and this effort could easily be further incentivised with an "accepted answer" tag and a few sweet, sweet extra points :)

I'm not sure how big of a "problem" this is (if at all), so I'd like to check what other members think about whether this needs addressing, and/or how to best address it.

[Something similar has been discussed on [this other Bioacoustics Meta post](https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79/should-we-be-accepting-answers-sooner-than-later).]

Answer (score 2):

Good question for discussion. I have noticed this and thought about it as well, and I have two theories

(1) Someone comes and asks a question and then gets lots of great answers, moves on with their life, and doesn't think about coming back to accept the answer.

A possible solution if this is the case is to comment on the original question, tagging the OP, and encourage them to accept an answer if they felt one was the best answer to their question. I think if it is a type of question that has a very clear answer and one answer appears to be a very strong front runner, than it would justify making such a comment (but would love to hear other opinions!)

(2) Many of the early questions on the private beta were more broad/had many possible answers so those questions aren't as easy to accept a single answer for. For example, [I asked about recorders for my iPhone.](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/617/recommendations-for-external-microphone-for-smartphone-for-casual-recordings-bi) A particular solution that exactly provides what I'm looking for has not yet been shared in the answers, so I haven't yet accepted an answer because I'm hoping more possible solutions will be provided!

In this case, I don't think it makes sense to accept an answer just for the sake of accepting.

Happy to hear others thoughts!

Comment: Periodically if I see a question that has a good answer (in some cases the OP even comments on that answer that it was great), I put a comment on the original question so that it will show in their 'inbox' and hopefully they will accept the answer.